# Is there a way to see players' MMR after I have exited from that particular match?

Tags: dota-2

After a ranked match ends, I can see players' MMR on the summary sheet, but I often tend to close it without taking a look. Afterwards, how can I look at the players' MMR?

Answer (score 5):

I only know four ways to know player's MMR :

- At the end of game with the scoreboard.
- On the player's profile, if you are friends on steam.
- On the leaderboard if the player is in the top 200 mmr (5800+ mmr). (http://www.dota2.com/leaderboards#europe)
- On a tracking Website, if the player is registered.
  (http://dota2toplist.com/solo)